# Filter is not working as expected when it is applied on a DF(Which is a union of 2 DF's) in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data Frame a:

```
SN  Hash_id Name
111 11ww11  Airtel
222 null    Idea
```

Data Frame b:

```
SN  Hash_id Name
333 null    BSNL
444 22ee11  Vodafone
```

Performing a UnionAll on these dataframes by column name as below:

```
def unionByName(a: DataFrame, b: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val columns = a.columns.toSet.intersect(b.columns.toSet).map(col).toSeq
    a.select(columns: _*).unionAll(b.select(columns: _*))
}
```

The result is: Data Frame c

```
SN  Hash_id Name
111 11ww11  Airtel
222 null    Idea
333 null    BSNL
444 22ee11  Vodafone
```

performing a filter on Data frame c.

```
val withHashDF = c.where(c("Hash_id").isNotNull)
val withoutHashDF = c.where(c("Hash_id").isNull)
```

The result for `withHashDF` is: it gives result only for Data frame a

```
111 11ww11  Airtel
```

The record form the Data Frame b is missing where the hash id is present:

```
444 22ee11  Vodafone
```

The result for `withoutHashDF` is:

```
222 null    Idea
BSNL 333    null    
null  222    Idea
```

In this DF the column values are not as per column name and the count is 3 where it should be only 2.From Data Frame "a" row is repeating.

Comment: It should work fine. Seems like issue from where unionByName method is called and where dataframe c is geting populated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `unionByName` there is a small change in getting `columns`

change from

```
val columns = a.columns.toSet.intersect(b.columns.toSet).map(col).toSeq
```

to

```
val columns = a.columns.intersect(b.columns).map(row => new Column(row)).toSeq
```

then it should work as expected.

Look at the complete code snippet & outcome below:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val dataFrameA = Seq(("111", "11ww11", "Airtel"),("222", null, "Idea")).toDF("SN","Hash_id", "Name")
val dataFrameB = Seq(("333", null, "BSNL"),("444", "22ee11", "Vodafone")).toDF("SN","Hash_id", "Name")

def unionByName(a: DataFrame, b: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val columns = a.columns.intersect(b.columns).map(row => new Column(row)).toSeq
  a.select(columns: _*).union(b.select(columns: _*))
}

val dataFrameC = unionByName(dataFrameA, dataFrameB)
val withHashDF = dataFrameC.where(dataFrameC("Hash_id").isNotNull)
val withoutHashDF = dataFrameC.where(dataFrameC("Hash_id").isNull)

println("dataFrameC")
dataFrameC.show()

println("withHashDF")
withHashDF.show

println("withoutHashDF")
withoutHashDF.show
```

output:

```
dataFrameC
+---+-------+--------+
| SN|Hash_id|    Name|
+---+-------+--------+
|111| 11ww11|  Airtel|
|222|   null|    Idea|
|333|   null|    BSNL|
|444| 22ee11|Vodafone|
+---+-------+--------+

withHashDF
+---+-------+--------+
| SN|Hash_id|    Name|
+---+-------+--------+
|111| 11ww11|  Airtel|
|444| 22ee11|Vodafone|
+---+-------+--------+

withoutHashDF
+---+-------+----+
| SN|Hash_id|Name|
+---+-------+----+
|222|   null|Idea|
|333|   null|BSNL|
+---+-------+----+
```

Comment: After changing the unionbyname also the results are not correct in my case. I am suspecting a dirty read is happening. But not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If there are duplicates in the Dataframe(Unionall),It gives unexpected results for filter or where clause. Once you eliminates the duplicates by using the distinct method, the results are as expected.